# Finding estimated date

Tags: sql

I want to get a `deliverydate` as `receivedate + 4` or `receivedate + 6` days and which should not fall on holidays and weekends.

```
SELECT * , case when column1 = column2 
then dateadd(d,4,receivedate) 
Else dateadd(d,6,Receiveddate) end As DeliveryDate 
from TableA
```

I could get the `deliverydate` date but it falls on holidays and weekends. How can I eliminate holidays and weekends from the code above?

Comment: Suggest you add more detail. What kind of db server are you using? There are calendar functions in MySQL, one of dbs we use. I also use Informix SE, which does not have calendar functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table that stores all of your holidays, weekends, and exceptions. I would include the weekend dates in the table because that rule may change in the future and not including certain dates is better than changing logic in my opinion.

Simply wrap your SQL in a loop (it really won't hurt performance much) that increments DeliveryDate  by 1 day until it is no longer an excluded date.

Here's an example of the logic in SQL Server

```
declare @test Table(
    baddate char(10)
)

insert into @test (baddate) values ('2011/12/17')
insert into @test (baddate) values ('2011/12/18')

declare @DeliveryDate char(10)

SELECT
    @DeliveryDate=CONVERT(VARCHAR,
    case
        when column1 = column2 then dateadd(d,4,Receiveddate) 
        Else dateadd(d,6,Receiveddate)
    end,111)
from (SELECT 'test' [column1], 'test' [column2],GETDATE() Receiveddate) a

While exists(SELECT * from @test WHERE baddate=@DeliveryDate)
BEGIN
    SET @DeliveryDate=CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(d,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,@DeliveryDate)),111)
END

SELECT @DeliveryDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you might be able to figure out w/e using a mod 7 trick, it wouldn't be that easy to deal with holidays. I suggest you let another non-db layer to figure this out.